# Cant crete a user with role manage-realm or manage-users

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Im using keycloak V23.0.1, im trying to use the python-keycloak to register new users to my keycloak bit im encounting the problem that when i try this way:

```
keycloack_client = KeycloakOpenIDConnection(server_url=f"http://{conf['keycloak_host']}:{conf['keycloak_port']}/",
                                    realm_name=conf['keycloak_realm'],
                                    client_id="realm-management",
                                    client_secret_key="8AfS63sha6VLPWzWI41TnNdUUQhnkw5r",
                                    username=conf['keycloak_admin_username'],
                                    password=conf['keycloak_admin_password'],
                                    user_realm_name=conf['keycloak_realm'],
                                    timeout=5)
    kc_admin = KeycloakAdmin(connection=keycloack_client)

await kc_admin.create_user( { "email": userdata.email,
                                "username": userdata.username,
                                "enabled": True,
                                "firstName": "",
                                "lastName": "",
                                "credentials": [{"value": userdata.password,"type": "password",}]}, exist_ok=False)
```

I got for answer 403: uknwown error

Searching i found that the user i used in connection must have manage-realm or maange-users roles. But i cant set them.

When i enter keycloak users -> click user -> role mapping -> assign role -> filter by client
I dont find any of those two roles.

Does someone know how to this in this version?

I tried adding the role but i couldnt

EDIT:
I was skipping it, it was in the second page of client filter